# Why can you feel voltage when ungrounded?

Tags: voltage

I regularly test for voltage with my fingers. When wearing boots and touching nothing but the live wire, why can I feel tingling on a live wire? It's not a shock, as I'm not grounded. I used to touch thumb to ground and finger to wire to test it. (Do not try this at home!!) That is, until I figured out they tingle, when live, and I'm ungrounded. I still do it. It's easier than getting the meter. I've never been shocked this way other than through finger and thumb method. Please no safety lectures. Been doing it for 30 years. Never been shocked except for the finger thumb method (that is the point of that one, to direct the current from finger to thumb.)

Comment: your body acts as a capacitor .... since you are touching a source of an alternating current, there is a small amount of charge that enters and leaves your body 60 times per second

Comment: Thank you! You should answer it instead of comment. I can't vote up on comments

Comment: done, but i think that Cristobol answered first

Answer (score 3):

Your body capacitance allows for enough current to stimulate your nerve endings.  I still have to weigh in on the safety...damp soles on your shoes could dramatically affect the outcome.  I know, no problems for 30 years...yet.

Comment: I'm a risk taker.  Thank you for your concern. Guess I can't vote up yet

Comment: I screwed up here you answered first. Did not know I can only choose one answer forgive me

Comment: @Johnl. (hit the check mark under the voting system)

Comment: I hit the check on Justin and you. It only works once. I won't make that mistake again. Sorry again

Answer (score 1):

Your body acts as a capacitor.

Since you are touching a source of an alternating current, there is a small amount of charge that enters and leaves your body 60 times per second.

Answer (score 1):

You are never *really* ungrounded. There is always some capacitance between you and the ground. What you are feeling is the tiny current that flows via this capacitive coupling to ground.

Answer (score -3):

You are also feeling the magnetic fields created when charging a battery from the iron and other magnetic elements in your body.

Comment: No, humans have no ability to sense magnetic fields (though some birds do). I don't understand where you think a battery comes into it.